# Can I use a subset defined from characteristics of individuals from original sample as a sample itself?

Tags: sampling

I have stratified random sample of individuals which represents a large geography. Some of these individuals are self-employed. Can I take subset of these surveyed individuals who are self-employed and treat it as a sample of self-employed individuals from the same geography? I understand the answer is most likely no since distribution of self-employed across sub-geographies need not be same as broad demographic distribution. But then this is not an indirect sample as well, like sample of children drawn from sample of parents. So is there a way to use this subset to say anything about underlying population?

Comment: Does https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/78446 answer your question?  Or perhaps https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/536182?  Maybe https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/578263?  For more like these, please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=random+sample+subsample).